# Vim: All the Greek text in one file is now inverted question marks "¿¿¿¿¿¿¿, ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿."

Tags: vim, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

A few days ago I wanted to enter some maths symbols in a text in gVim (7.3, on windows 7 64 bits) so I changed the encoding to utf-16 with

```
"set enc=utf-16"
```

I also changed the font to DejaVu Sans Mono (because it has all the symbols I needed).

Merrily, I edited my text, then saved it and closed it and went on to do other things. I then noticed that all the new text files I created were created as utf-16.

D'oh. "set enc" changes the encoding for the editor, not the buffer. So I changed it back to utf-8. Then I opened some files I had created in the meantime and they were all full of "@" signs.

Uh oh. ++enc to the rescue:

```
e ++enc=utf-8
```

After that, it's a bit fuzzy in my mind. I think I may have opened a file with Greek text to find it full of "^Z" characters and updated its encoding again.

What I know for sure is that last night I checked that Greek file and all the Greek text in it is now replaced by inverted question marks:

```
- ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿ ¿¿¿ ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿
    > callista chione (¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿)
    > Venus verrucosa (¿¿¿¿¿¿)
```

And so on. The encoding is set to utf-8 and changing it doesn't really do anything anymore. I can tell that I can not recover that text... probably. Somehow, at some point, I issued a sequence of commands that resulted in a loss of information.

I should also say that the file's backup (ending in ~) is also scrambled and although I didn't attempt to recover the swap file, I can see that the timestamp is from last night, when I first noticed the problem.

Is that really the end? Does entropy really win this time? Does anyone know of a way to get back that lost text, or some part of it?

Answer (score 1):

If all you have are those same inverted question marks `¿` (U+00BF), it looks indeed that "entropy has won". You've probably already checked on the raw file (using a hex dump), or via `ga` inside Vim.

The only thing that could save you is a backup, but I guess you haven't got any. Learn from this and start using one right now. There are many choices, and you can also "misuse" a version control system like Git for it. There are also very lightweight backup solutions for Vim, e.g. my [writebackup plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1828).

Comment: Actually, I do have a backup, it's just not very recent :) I'm an accomplished packrat when it comes to notes etc and I do indeed "misuse" git like that to track my important text files (upvoted  your answer for the good advice).

Comment: I had a look with a hex editor, unfortunately it's all 00BF, no question about that :(